# Fetch 2 records for each group name of element of column 1 that in column 2 have the most value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that like below.  Now i want to fetch 2 records for each group name of element of column 1 that in column 2 have the most value. For example, Fetch 85 and 75 for A, 65 and 45 for B ... 
I use oracle database.
TNX

```
 ----------------------
 |Column 1 | Column 2 |
 ----------------------
 |    A    |    85    |
 ----------------------
 |    A    |    75    |
 ---------------------
 |    A    |    60    |
 ---------------------
 |    A    |    50    |
 ---------------------
 |    B    |    65    |
 ---------------------
 |    B    |    45    |
 ---------------------
 |    B    |    35    |
 ---------------------
 |    B    |    25    |
 ---------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as seq 
      from table t
     ) t
where seq <= 2;
```

However, `fetch first . . .` clause also helpful :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.col2 in (select t1.col2
                 from table t1
                 where t1.col1 = t.col1
                 order by t1.col2 desc
                 fetch first 2 rows only
                );
```

Comment: TNX. Your first query is ok, but second query is wrong. The resault of second query is not equal by another.

Answer (score 0):

Try using row_number()

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as rn
from tablename
) A where rn in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number` window function

```
with t1 as
(
 select col1,col2
 ,row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col2 desc) rn 
 from table_name
) select * from t1 where rn<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Here is demo [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/498b8/16/0)

SQL

```
select col1,col2 from (select col1,col2, rank() over(partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as rn from t) q where q.rn<=2;
```